# How to permanently delete file from the Android shell without root

Tags: android, shell, terminal, delete-file

I'm creating an Android application for which I need to delete a confidential image of such a kind that it won't be possible to restore it, at least not easily.
The solution I'm exploring is to use the my shell access without root.
With Android shell I can delete the file with the linux command `'rm'`.

I was wondering how to use commands like linux `shred` or `srm` without having to install it because I don't have root access. Can i run a linux package as portable version?

The file can be in the application directory `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp`.

No ADB, No Java.

Comment: You do not need root for that directory. Below Android 11 its accessable for all apps.

Comment: no, i do not need it, i can use another directory or my own directory app which do not need root. And i do not worry about the access by other because i want to delete it rigth away after processing it.

Comment: Your answer does not clarify anything.

Comment: in clear i said **No** to your question. thanks

Comment: You could write random bytes to the file, multiple times, or a set of patterns, then finally delete the file. The secure delete programs (`shred` etc) won't be doing anything fancier than that.

Comment: How to write random bytes on image file? I thought of this and tried `echo "test" > myImage.jpg` was not working. the commad `dd ` did not do nothing.

Comment: shred (or any overwriting method) is useless on emmc flash drive because of the underlaying FTL you will never target the file again. on FBE encryption (which is forced by android 10) a simple `rm` is enough, it's impossible to recover. same is true for FDE encryption (only if dm-0 respects the discard flag, should be fixed meanwhile)

Comment: you should be care more about apps like google photos in background continuously uploading pictures to cloud. `.nomedia` will (hopefully) avoid